# Problema al intentar crear un data frame a partir de otro creado con la función merge

Tags: base-de-datos, r, dataframe

Buenas tardes desde Canarias. Necesito una base de datos que contenga las variables (columnas) de otras 2 bases de datos, concretamente, de la encuesta nacional de salud a los hogares(**MICRODAT_CH**) y de la encuesta nacional de salud de los adultos(**MICRODAT_CA**). 
Como ya he explicado, quiero juntar estas 2 bases de datos de ambas encuestas y luego quedarme con unas variables determinadas. 
Para unir ambas bases de datos, creo una nueva utilizando la función merge y unimos los datos con la variable IDENTHOGAR

Sin embargo, al  **intentar** crear el data frame(**DATA1**) con las variables que necesito a partir de **MICRODAT_CA_CH**, me aparece el siguiente error:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(MICRODAT_CA_CH, , c("CCAA", "IDENTHOGAR", "ESTRATO",  : 
>     undefined columns selected.

¿Hay algún error en la sintaxis?¿puede que haya cometido algún error con la función merge?

```
MICRODAT_CA_CH <- merge(MICRODAT_CA,MICRODAT_CH,by = "IDENTHOGAR")
DATA1<-MICRODAT_CA_CH[,c("CCAA","IDENTHOGAR","ESTRATO","SEXO_i","EDAD_i","NADULTOS",
                         "SEXOa","EDADa","ACTIVa","E4","E4b","NIVEST","F6","F11","F13","F14a",
                         "G21","G22","G23","G24","H26_1","H26_2","H26")]
```

En realidad necesito muchas más variables, pero tanto si introduzco en DATA1 solo unas pocas o todas las que necesito, aparece el mismo error.
Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente el error lo que te esta diciendo es que algunas de las columnas o variables que defines en la selección, NO existe, es decir alguna de estas:

```
c("CCAA","IDENTHOGAR","ESTRATO","SEXO_i","EDAD_i","NADULTOS", "SEXOa","EDADa","ACTIVa","E4",
  "E4b","NIVEST","F6","F11","F13","F14a", "G21","G22","G23","G24","H26_1","H26_2","H26")
```

Podría ser un error tipográfico, pero me inclino más a un comportamiento habitual de la función `merge()` cuando tienes columnas con el mismo nombre en los dos `data.frames`. Por ejemplo:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A=1:5, B=runif(5))
df2 <- data.frame(A=1:5, B=runif(5), C=runif(5))

merge(df1, df2, by="A")

  A       B.x        B.y         C
1 1 0.7947576 0.09025004 0.5928363
2 2 0.2040057 0.36907034 0.3017770
3 3 0.5835458 0.99526117 0.5952890
4 4 0.3145777 0.90507526 0.8671587
5 5 0.8187764 0.62291439 0.9062194
```

Se observa, que la columna `B` es compartida por ambos `df´s`, por lo que automáticamente  se las renombra con el postfijo `.x` y `.y`. Revisa previamente los nombres finales de `MICRODAT_CA_CH` mediante `names(MICRODAT_CA_CH)` y ajusta los nombres o en su defecto utiliza la selección por el índice posicional de la columna que se desentiende del nombre.